# Id from PHP not being passed to URL

Tags: php, html

I have some data displayed from SQL to PHP, when the user clicks the eye icon, he is redirected to another page with id on the URL, I did the following code

```
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $record['id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $record['firstname'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $record['Email'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $record['mobilenumber']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $record['company']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $record['designation']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $record['state']?></td>
    <td><a href="detail.php?id=$record['id']\"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Instead of the id, some special characters are coming in the URL, how can I fix it?

Comment: it is an php block?

Comment: @DevsiOdedra i did not understand what you said

Comment: There is a shorthand syntax for the PHP blocks, if all you want to do in the block is one echo. Instead of `<?php echo $a; ?>` you could write `<?= $a ?>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is how your anchor tag should be.

```
<a href="detail.php?id=<?php echo $record['id']; ?>\"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

You need to enclose the $record variable inside php tags and echo it.

Answer (score 2):

You should echo it, like you did with another values:

```
<?php echo $record['id']; ?>
```

Full code:

```
<tr>
      <td><?php echo $record['id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $record['firstname'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $record['Email'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $record['mobilenumber']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $record['company']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $record['designation']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $record['state']?></td>
<td><a href="detail.php?id=<?php echo $record['id']; ?>\"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
  <?php } ?>
```

Comment: @TEIA2019 You already did it with another values, but not with this one .. :P

Answer (score 0):

**You should echo `ID`**

*as below*

```
<a href="detail.php?id=<?= $record['id'] ?>\">
```